# Object not visible in render even when it is not disabled in rendering

Tags: rendering, visibility

When I render, the object shown in the image is not visible in render, even when the `disable in the render` is checked. I would like to know how this is happenening? Here is my .blend file-
http://www.mediafire.com/file/64n3e7l4hzio3dv/nami_no_lacagues.blend/file

[image]

[image]

Comment: Only thing i can think of at the moment is that maybe you have multiple view-layers with different settings. If not, i think it is hard to figure out what's going on without a .blend file. You could consider uploading one here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: my bleder files is larger than 30 mb (35). What should i do?

Comment: You could use an alternative upload location. Or make a copy of the file with some elements responsible for a considerable chunk of the file size deleted (like geometry or textures not relevant to the issue), provided of course the issue remains : ) Up to you.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/64n3e7l4hzio3dv/nami_no_lacagues.blend/file

Comment: As @Fjorsteller said the only solution I could find was to apply the Surface Deform modifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a whole answer: I've figured out what happens, but not why. I thought it best to share it anyway since it might help.

In the 3D Viewport the object seems to be affected by the Surface Deform modifier. But for rendering it is not. When rendered it is in the shape (and location) where it would be without the Surface Deform modifier.

If you render the character from the back you can see the object in this location, partly hidden in the body of the character.

[image]

A possible solution is to Apply the the Surface Deform modifier on the object.

Comment: This response works for me!! thanks you help me a looot! :DDD